# Javascript - Using a For Loop to build Mulitple arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I feel like this should be easier to find online, but I haven't been able to find anything about it.

So my question is, can I use the total amount from an existing array to build that many separate arrays and auto populate them?

### Can you Build Multiple Arrays using a For Loop based on the value amount of an existing array?

```
var arrA = ["box 1", "box 2", "box 3"]; 

for (i = 0; i < arrA.length; i++) {
  var arr[i] =[
    "Style[i]",
    "ListA[i]",
    "ListB[i]"
  ];
}
```

This doesn't work, but the result I am looking for is an output like this

```
var arr1 = ["Style1","ListA1","ListB1"];
var arr2 = ["Style2","ListA2","ListB2"];
. . . .
```

and continue repeating for the amount of times based on the Array length?

Comment: What's the expected output or result ?

Comment: So when I add "box 4" to the first array, it will automatically generate the next array, rather than having to write the entire thing out each time.

Comment: What is the next array ? What is the expected result ?

Comment: "var arr[i]" ?!!

Comment: You question is unclear, if you want a response please clarify your question. See [ask] and provide additional information like how many other arrays you want, what should theses array contain and how they are related with the first one.

Comment: @MickaelB. 
I'm not sure how to make it any more clear. 
I want to be able to add "box 4" to the first array, and have a for loop that will see that there is now a total of 4 instead of 3 in the array and then build a fourth array "arr4" that will contain 
     "style4","listA4","ListB4".

Comment: `var arrA = ["box 1", "box 2", "box 3", "box 4"];` done.

Comment: @Guardian_808 Are the new arrays supposed to be separate variables or all part of one object? What goes in these new arrays? What should the new arrays be named?

Comment: question is not very clear. those `box 1`, `box 2` are arrays? you wrote them as string...

Comment: Write a function which takes a parameter and add that parameter to the array. Then check the length of the array and create arr[arrA.length -1] = desired array.

Comment: @chandan_kr_jha what is "desired array" ?

Comment: @Mickael The array which he wants to create. Clearly they should not be string mistaken as array elements.

Comment: What should be in this array ? Who is "he" ?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this ?

```js
const arrA = ["box 1", "box 2", "box 3"]; 

const arrB = arrA.map((c,i)=>[`Style${i+1}`,`ListA${i+1}`,`ListB${i+1}`])

console.log( arrB )
```

Comment: This sort of works, but I'd need them to come out as arrays, 
     Arr1 = ["style1","ListA1","ListB1"];
     Arr2 = ["style2","ListA2","ListB2"];
etc..

Comment: @Guardian_808  bad idea, in this case prefer to use a meta object tou build your array list

Answer (score 0):

What about a function that takes the original, and the new array in, and returns the result.

```
let addArray = (original, newArray) => {
  let result = original.push(newArray)
  return result
}

//Not sure what's meant by auto-populating them...But this 
//Will take an array of arrays, and simply push "newArray" into 
// "original" array of arrays.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you want to dynamically create some arrays from a given array.
I think you can do it this way

```js
let arrA = ["box 1", "box 2", "box 3"]; 
let generatedArrays = {};
for (let i = 0 ; i< arrA.length ; i++){
 generatedArrays[arrA[i]] = []
 }
 console.log(generatedArrays)
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm aiming for, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this by creating two functions, one to initialize the first list of arrays (called once, at the beginning) and the one one is called every time you add a new item to the first array as so:

```js
//first (master) array
var arrA = ["box 1", "box 2", "box 3"];
//array to hold individual box's array
var arrBoxes = []

function createInitArrays() {
  for (i = 0; i < arrA.length; i++) {
    arrBoxes[i] = [
      "Style" + (i + 1),
      "ListA" + (i + 1),
      "ListB" + (i + 1)
    ];
  }
}


function createNewArray() {
  var index = arrA.length
  arrBoxes[index] = [
    "Style" + (index+1),
    "ListA" + (index+1),
    "ListB" + (index+1)
  ];
}

//call to create initial arrays
createInitArrays()
// call to create new array every time you update 'arrA'
// createNewArray()

// display list of arrays based on 'arrA'
console.log(arrBoxes)
```